# How to limit the number of digits?

Tags: python, function, return, digit

What should I add to my code to make return value `15.58`, without using any library ?

```
def solution(side):
  result = (side**2)*(3**(0.5))/4
  return result

# return = 15.5885
```

Comment: maybe you should add the name of the language to your code

Comment: I meant in python

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you mean you want to round the result to the nearest hundredth? What kind of rounding to you want--up, down, 4/5, banker's/symmetric, or you don't care? Which particular result do you want for your example: `15.58` or `15.59`? Do you need the answer to be exact or will the usual floating-point values (which will be very near the value you seek but probably not exactly equal to it) suffice? Are you talking about returning a particular value or printing it to look the particular way?

Comment: when i use;
def solution(side):

  result = (side**2)*(3**(0.5))/4

  result = round(result,2)

  return result

it gives result as 15.59

 Actually I want to learn how to round up and down, but if we consider this case i want it to be rounded down

Comment: Please look up rounding in Python.

Comment: I did but, Im trying to make this code work in web browser because it's mini puzzle in www.codela.io. The main issue is, the example question has to be solved without library. Adding library is forbidden and the exact value has to be rounded down. @Norrius

Comment: I want it to be round down without using any library @RoryDaulton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original** result value: `15.5884572681`

Use `floor` to round down to get `15.58`:

```
import math
def solution(side): 
    result = (side**2)*(3**(0.5))/4 
    return math.floor(result*100)/100
print(solution(6))  # prints 15.58
```

Use `round` with precision `2` to get `15.59`:

```
def solution(side): 
    result = (side**2)*(3**(0.5))/4 
    return round(result,2)
print(solution(6))  # prints 15.59
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def solution(side):
   result = (side**2)*(3**(0.5))/4
   return round(result,2)
```

# return = 15.59

Comment: How can i round it down, i mean  # return = 15.58

Comment: Don't just post code. Please add an explanation of why this would answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use round to ceil value :

```
# First we take a float and convert it to a decimal
result = (side**2)*(3**(0.5))/4

# Then we round it to 2 places
output = round(result,2)
print output
```

You can use math.floor to get 15.58 :

```
import math
result = (math.floor(result * 100)) / 100.0// 15.58
```

Comment: Check out update answer to get easiest way to get right answer @theausome